# XSD: Have a date element be either empty or meet restrictions

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have an XSD, and I need a date element to be either empty or be after a certain date (10/1/2015).

So, the following should be allowed:

```
<DDate></DDate>
<DDate>2015-10-10</DDate>
```

My XSD is defined as:

```
<xs:element name = "DDate" nillable="true" >
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
            <xs:minInclusive value="2015-10-01"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

This enforces that the date is correct, but does not allow the date to be empty. Any insight or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition already allows an empty `DDate`, except for one restriction, you must also specify `xsi:nil="true"`, like so:

```
<!-- ns decl. should go to the root element -->
<DDate xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xsd-date-empty.xsd" 
    xsi:nil="true" />
```

But, if with "allow empty", you mean that you want to allow whitespace, and/or empty nodes without the use of `xsi:nil`, there are many ways to do that. I would probably go with a union, like this:

```
<xs:element name = "DDate" nillable="true" >
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:union>
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="2015-10-01"/>
                </xs:restriction>        
            </xs:simpleType>            
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
                    <xs:length value="0" />
                </xs:restriction>        
            </xs:simpleType>            
        </xs:union>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Which means nothing more than allow either a:

- date with minInclusive restrictions
- string that is empty after whitespace is collapsed

Answer (score 2):

Generally, to allow "X or nothing" in an element, you have three options:

(a) declare the element nillable. But this requires the instance to have the attribute xsi:nil='true'. I hate this approach and never use it, but I mention it for completeness.

(b) declare the type to be a union of X and a string constrained to have length zero. (as Abel suggests)

(c) declare the type to be a list of X with maxLength 1. This tends to be my own preference.

The choice between (b) and (c) may depend on how you use the schema. If it's just for validation, both work equally well. If it's for schema-aware XSLT and XQuery processing, the list type works better, though unions start to become well supported in the 3.0 versions. If it's for data binding in Java or C#, you'll have to ask someone else, that's not my area.